# How can detect error when boost memory mapped file allocated more disk space than is free on HDD

Tags: c++, linux, boost, mmap

In my modelling code I use boost [memory mapped files](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/mapped_file.html), to allocate large-ish arrays on disk.

It works well, but I couldn't find a way to detect situation in which I allocate array which is larger than free space on disk drivw. For example following code will execute happily (assuming that I have less than 8E9 bytes of free space on HDD):

```
    boost::iostreams::mapped_file_params file_params;

    file_params.path = path;
    file_params.mode = std::ios::in | std::ios::out;
    file_params.new_file_size = static_cast<size_t>(8E9); # About 10GB
    file_params.length = static_cast<size_t>(8E9);

    boost::iostreams::mapped_file result;

    result.open(file_params);
```

I can even work on `resuld.data()` until I write to part of memory which is not allocted (becaue of missing space on HDD) and then I get a following error:

```
 memory access violation at address: 0x7e9e2cd1e000: non-existent physical address
```

Is there any way to detect this error before I get cryptic `memory access violation`?

I actually tested this: if file is bigger than avilable free space on partition it code has memory access violation, if it is smaller the code works (I tested it by changing space free on the partition not by editing the code).

**Possible solutions**

If I `std:fill` file contents with zeroes I still get `memory access violation`, but this error is located near the allocation and easier to debug. I'd rather want some way to raise an exception.

Comment: For me it doesn't look like your running out of diskspace but you're accessing memory out size of the range you've mapped. Is ir really 1E11 not 0x1E11 ?

Comment: This is totally related to disk space, and I really get this error. If I allocate 8GB on my `/tmp` (that has size of 10GB) code works, if I write 2.5GB file to this partition it explodes with this error. This might be some obscure bug in boost --- it could be silently truncating space (in which case I would indeed access memory out of range).

Comment: @user I edited the question --- I really assumed that numbers were irrelevant. In reality it is about 8 GB, numbers should reflect that now. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: structured exception handling is older than LINUX. But for some reason unclear to me, it has not made it into LINUX. Thus find an OS which provides it and then you will be able to deal with out_of_disk_space problems when they occur. On the other hand, LINUX_OUT_OF_MEMORY killer tells me, that some LINUX developers consider such scenarios unlikely (grin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `fallocate` or `posix_fallocate` to actually reserve space for the file up front. This way you know you won't ever "over-commit". It has a performance drawback, of course upon initial creation.

For security reasons the OS is likely to zero out the blocks on `fallocate`.

`fallocate` lets you do unwritten extents, but it still zeros upon first access.
On windows, this can be combated using, `SetFileValidData` lets you bypass even that.

Note that Linux with `O_DIRECT` + `fallocate()`, still uses considerable CPU (as opposed to Windows' `SetFileValidData`), and although IO bandwidth is usually the bottleneck, this could still have noticeable performance effect if you are doing much CPU work at the same time.

Comment: Is there any way to do this while retaining platform independence? While this is not a strict requirement --- for now whole applicaiton is written using platform-independent tools, and losing this would be a minor pain.

Comment: I think `posix_fallocate` might be support across the board.

Comment: Well at least on all posix systems. Maybe I wasn't really clear: it would be really nice if this solution also worked on Windows.

Comment: @jb. Windows implements large parts (all?) of POSIX. Has done so for many years. I'd check it.

Comment: probably you are right. Windows does implement some parts of posix. And even if not I will definetely be able to use cygwin compatiblility layer.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to detect this error before I get cryptic memory access violation?

When you just change the size of a file it will be `sparse`, that means the areas without data do not consume disk space. Space is allocated during writes - and can create out of diskspace errors.

A way to solve the problem would be to write (dummy) data to the file instead of just changing the size. That takes more time but you would get the out of diskspace during this first write cycle only, as the file has its final size afterwards.

Comment: This is more or less what I do now, but it doesn't solve my problem if I: ``std::fill(result.data(), result.data()+this->array_size_bytes, 0);``. I still get a `` memory access violation``. This violation is much easier to debug, but still. I'd rather want some error I can intercept and then print some helpfull info to console.